# Sending compiled angular template as mail body

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I have this template named test.html:

```
mynameis: {{mynameis}}
```

I then have a controller with the following code:

```
$scope.mynameis = 'slim shady';
var newScope = $scope.$new();
var newElem = '<ng-src><div ng-include="\'./test.html\'" ></div></ng-src>';
var emailtext = angular.element(newElem);
var myres = $compile(emailtext)(newScope);

$timeout(function(){
    console.log('OUTPUT',myres[0].innerHTML);
    console.log('OUTPUT ALL',myres[0]);
    var htmlEmaiBody = emailtext.html();
    var ToRecipients = [{EmailAddress: {Address: 'myemail@gmail.com'}}];
    var emailPayload = {Message: {Subject: 'subject',Body: {ContentType: 'Html',Content: '<b>manual html</b><br>'+htmlEmaiBody},ToRecipients: ToRecipients}};
    Office365MailService().messages().sendOnFly(emailPayload).then(function () {
        console.log('email sent');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('email not sent');
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Office365MailService is only another function that sends a mail.
NB: This worked before. Some change must have been made, as it is not working anymore.

What I see in the console is:

```
OUTPUT <!-- ngInclude: './test.html' -->
```

But I also see the text "OUTPUT ALL" with this html-structure:

```
<ng-src class="ng-scope"><!-- ngInclude: './test.html' --><div ng-include="'./test.html'" class="ng-scope"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">mynameis: slim shady</span></div></ng-src>
```

The mail I receive only contains the bolded "manual html".

I then have a look at the source of the message in my email client and I see this at the end:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=>
</head>
<body>
<b>manual html</b><br>
<!-- ngInclude: './views/matching/testTemplate.html' -->
</body>
</html>
```

Why? Isn't the template getting compiled or what? I'm doing this in the timeout as I learned you have to wait for the compile-function to be ready. But still, nothing from the test.html-template is included.
However, in the output to the console, the name "slim shady" was printed from the template. So the problem should NOT be that the template is not compiled and ready. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a callback when loading the template.

```
$templateRequest(templateName).then(function(template) {
```

The code above is the first thing to do. Then in the callback you can use compile and timeout. Otherwise, with my old code, the compilation of the template was one on a template that could haven't been fetched yet.
SO it was an async-issue.